# How to serialize data from processing.js to rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, processing

I am creating a simple canvas using processing.js , how to pass values from rails application to Processing.js

```
void drawBox(int bx, int by, int bs, int bs){
      strokeWeight(3); 
      stroke(50,50,50);
      // Test if the cursor is over the box 
      if (mouseX > bx-bs && mouseX < bx+bs && 
          mouseY > by-bs && mouseY < by+bs) {
        bover = true;
       if(!locked) { 
          fill(181,213,255);
        } 
      } else {
        fill(255);
          bover = false;
      }
      fill(192);
      stroke(64);
      roundRect(bx, by,80,30,10,10);
      // put in text 
      if (!isRight) {
        text("Box Value", x-size+5, y-5);
      //Here i need to pass value from my controller
      }
      else {
        text("Box Value", x+5, y-5);  
 //Here i need to pass value from my controller    
      }
    }
```

Instead of static string "Box Value" , I need to pass the value from the ex @post.name through ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with some RJS template where you set a global variable to the text or use a data store to attach it to a DOM element. Then in your processing.js, just use the variable to render your text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add pure javascript into your processing code : http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/jsQuickStart#mixingjsandprocessing

So, retrieving your data from AJAX with your favorite library should be easy.